# Why am i getting unorderable types error

Tags: python

```
import random

while True:
    dice1=random.randint (1,6)
    dice2=random.randint (1,6)


strengthone = input ("Player 1, between 1 and 10 What do you want your characters strength to be? Higher is not always better.")
skillone = input ("Player 1, between 1 and 10 What do you want your characters skill to be? Higher is not always better.")

if str(strengthone) > int(10):
    print ("Incorrect value")
else:
    print ("Good choice.")
if skillone > 10:
    print ("Incorrect value.")
else:
    print ("Good choice.")

strengthtwo = input ("Player 2, between 1 and 10 what do you want your characters strength to be? Higher is not always better.")
skilltwo = input ("Player 2, between 1 and 10 what do you want your characters skill to be? Higher is not always better.")

if strengthtwo > 10:
    print ("Incorrect value.")
else:
    print ("Good choice.")
if skillone > 10:
    print ("Incorrect value.")
else:
    print ("Good choice.")

strengthmod = strengthone - strengthtwo
skillmod = skillone - skilltwo

print ("Player 1, you rolled a", str(dice1))
print ("Player 2, you rolled a", str(dice2))



if dice1 == dice2:
    print ("")
if dice1 > dice2:
    newstrengthone = strengthmod + strengthone
    newskillone = skillmod + skillone
if dice2 > dice1:
    newstrengthtwo = strengthmod + strengthtwo
    newskilltwo = skillmod + skilltwo
if dice1 < dice2:
    newstrengthone = strengthmod - strengthone
    newskillone = skillmod - skillone
if dice2 < dice1:
    newstrengthtwo = strengthmod - strengthtwo
    newskilltwo = skillmod - skilltwo

if strengthone == 0:
    print ("Player one dies, well done player two. You win!")
if strengthtwo == 0:
    print ("Player two dies, well done player one. You win!")
if newstrengthone == 0:
    print ("Player one dies, well done player two. You win!")
if newstrengthtwo == 0:
    print ("Player two dies, well done player one. You win!")

break
```

Its for a school project so the objective of the code wont make much sense. I had some syntax errors because of indentations. I got them sorted now i have this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Computing\Task 3\Program.py", line 11, in <module>
    if str(strengthone) > int(10):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `int(10)` and `10` are the same thing; so you can do `if int(strengthone) > 10:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot compare `str` and `int`. So change

   ```
   if str(strengthone) > int(10):
   ```

   to

   ```
   if int(strengthone) > int(10):
   ```
2. And converting 10 to `int` is unnecessary, because it already is an int.

   ```
   print (type(10)) # <type 'int'>
   ```

   So, this can be written like this

   ```
   if int(strengthone) > 10:
   ```
3. Even better, you can convert the values coming right out of `input`, to their corresponding types

   ```
   strengthone = int(input ("Player 1,..."))
   skilltwo = int(input ("Player 2,..."))
   ```

   So, that you can compare the values like this

   ```
   if strengthone > 10:
   ```

Comment: ... and do the same for `skillone`, `strengthtwo`, and all the other strings you compare to integers, or when you substract those strings from each other.

Comment: @tobias_k Sorry, I didnt get what you are saying. Could you please explain?

Comment: My comment was unclear, by "you" I was referring to OP, but at the same time suggesting it as an addition to your answer (instead of posting a very similar answer myself). Best would be to convert it directly when getting the input, since they are treated like integers all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`if str(strengthone) > int(10):`

to

`if strengthone.isdigit() and int(strengthone) > 10:`